# Mathlive -> Vertical scroll is not working in

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created a mathfield input with height 180px and overflow auto so when I am scrolling the content in horizontally its working but when i am trying vertical scroll so its not working .

// ref element

```
<div className={styles.input}
    ref={this.editorRef} >
     {this.state.initialLatex || "#?"}
 </div>
```

//initialisation

```
componentDidMount() {
        document.body.append(this.container);
        this.editor = window.MathLive.makeMathField(this.editorRef.current, {
            onKeystroke: (e, keyCode) => {
                if (keyCode == "[Space]") {
                    this.insertLatex("\\,");
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

---

//styles

```
.input{
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height:18rem;
    width: 100%; 
    margin-right: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Facing the same. Any help guys?